# Loading Page in a Div using Jquery

Tags: jquery, dynamic

I am trying to load an aspx page into a Div. The first time around, I have a static link in the page and wrote
a function for the onclick event of the anchor tag similar to the below code

Update My Info

The JS function Navigate is

```
 function Navigate(URL) {
    $("#contentManagement").load(URL, { name: 'TNR Xtranet' }, 
       function (content) { 
        $(this).hide().fadeIn("slow"); return false; 
    });
    $("#content").hide();
 }
```

In the code behind for the UpdateINfo.aspx page, I do a Response.write("HTML String")

The second time around I am trying to use the same UpdateInfo.aspx page in the anchor tag above but am passing a few query string parameters as well. The parameters are all well formed here and the control goes over to the UpdateInfo.asps page but when the page finishes loading, I seem, to get an empty page and not the content inside Response.Write.

I have spent more than 3 hours on this and am at wits end. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things.

1. Is your resulting HTML well formed?
2. Can you try it without "return false;"?  I can seem to pinpoint it, but it has given me much grief from before.

Lemme know how it goes.

Comment: Return Fasle dosent seem to do the trick. Still stuck with the same problem. I tried doing a Respose.write('WORK"); and no other HTML on page load. Still the same problem, it works the first time around when no params are passed and the second time around a blank page.

Comment: replaced the function with

    function Navigate(URL) {
    $("#contentManagement").load(URL, '', function (response,    status, xhr) {
    $("#contentManagement").html(response); return false;
    });
    $("#content").hide();
    }
    
and it works fine.